# Placeholder image as Thumbnail(blurred) until actual image loads

Tags: swift, placeholder, blur, kingfisher

I have below code for showing full screen image once User selects it.

> fullImage.kf.setImage(with: url)

During the time the actual image downloads, I wanted to show a place holder as the same image but thumbnail size stretched out. This thumbnail was cached by Kingfisher library while showing thumbnails previously.

When I show the image with out KF library, by using regular iOS UIImage downloader it shows a blurred preview of thumbnail stretched and then it shows actual image. How can this be achieved with KF library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use Place holder image like below

```
fullImage.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
```

But to show thumbnail you must have thumbnail image downloaded separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the thumbnail to be an image form the web, you can do what people are suggesting [on GitHub](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/953).

```
let cacheImage = ImageCache.default.retrieveImageInDiskCache(forKey: "cache")

let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: imageURL, cacheKey: "cache")

imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource, placeholder: cacheImage, options: [.keepCurrentImageWhileLoading], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
```

You'll need to find a way to download the thumbnails first though, which can be done in multiple ways, e.g. using an `ImagePrefetcher`